# What is 'burning or baiting' about the verb 'stake'?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

> [stake (v.2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=stake&searchmode=none)   
>       "to risk, wager," 1520s, perhaps from notion of "post on which a gambling wager was placed" (see [stake](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stake&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.2)), though Weekley suggests "**there is a tinge of the burning or baiting metaphor**" in this usage. Meaning "to maintain surveillance" (usually stake out) is first recorded 1942, American English colloquial, probably form earlier sense of "mark off territory." ...

Alas, I struggle even to guess this metaphor. So what does **burning or baiting** mean here?

**Update:** I know that 'stake' can mean a "post upon which persons were bound for death by burning", but Etymonline cites this meaning for its entry on the [noun](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stake&allowed_in_frame=0). So how did **burning or baiting** affect the meaning of the verb above?

Comment: Sadly, Mr. Weekley died in 1954, else you could have asked him what he meant. Have you tried to locate the Weekley work obliquely alluded to in the definition you cited?

Comment: What is [*at stake*](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=at+stake&l=0), what is at risk, what will you wager (bet) or entice (bait) something on? Your health, your reputation, your money/finances or your life? [*He staked his reputation on a much-publicised plan that has demonstrably failed*](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=he+staked&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) If you understand the meaning of "to stake" then you can see how *burning* and *baiting/enticing* is related. If you don't understand the meaning that explains your confusion.

Comment: "Baiting" is the practice of, say, tying a lamb to a stake to attract a wolf.

Comment: Or the public "sport" of *bear-baiting*.

Comment: http://www.elizabethan-era.org.uk/elizabethan-bear-bull-baiting.htm

Answer (score 1):

LMGIFY

The "burning" metaphor refers to *burning at the stake*, a method of executing criminals.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_burning

For a specific example: see, e.g., *Joan of Arc*.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan_of_Arc

Comment: Thanks. I did know about this heroine. Does my updated OP help?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the "baiting" metaphor would be a reference to the use of stakes in animal trapping, both as anchors for ground traps and in the famous "pit with stakes at the bottom".  It also seems plausible that it may seem more bait-related because bait itself is able to be *staked* to the locality for an animal, as one would stake suet to a tree for woodpeckers.

I also assume the burning metaphor is, as suggested, a reference to burning people (or just other flammable material such as a bonfire) at a stake.  Weekley may have been suggesting that with those (perhaps) more common usages of the word, using it for wagering carries with it a tinge of the other meanings.  After all, one might consider a wager to be nothing but "burning your money", or from the other perspective, "baiting an unwary sucker" into making a poor bet.